# Pandas dataframe with int8 column showing inconsistent arithmetic (sum and product)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, integer

I have a dataframe with an `int8` column to ensure lower memory.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 50]}, dtype='int8')
        df
Out[1]:
     a
0   100
1   50

In [2]: df.dtypes
Out[2]: a    int8
        dtype: object
```

`sum` automatically promotes the result to `int64` and gives the correct result.

```
In [3]: df.sum()
Out[3]:
a    150
dtype: int64
```

But a `+` or `*` operation does not do so.

```
In [4]: df.loc[0, 'a'] + df.loc[1, 'a']
C:\Users\bubai\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_33164\1219674856.py:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in byte_scalars
  df.loc[0, 'a'] + df.loc[1, 'a']
Out[4]: -106
```

```
In [5]: df['a'] * 4
Out[5]: 0   -112
        1    -56
        Name: a, dtype: int8
```

So at one place `pandas` decides to automatically upcast the result whereas in other cases it does not. Is this an inconsistency in `pandas` or non-standard coding on my end? If I have such arithmetic operations in my code, how can I avoid the incorrect results?

Comment: The range of `int8` is `-128 to 127`. Read this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for some explanation on the representation.

Comment: @MYousefi, my query is regarding the inconsistency in the approach of `pandas` in upcasting the result in certain cases, while not in others. I just edited the statement of my final query to be more explicit regarding that point. Anything on that?

Comment: When you are adding the values you are adding an `int8` and `int8` through the `__add__` function of the `int8` class. Pandas is not doing anything here. Invoking `sum` is asking pandas to do it which will invoke through a different routine.

Comment: numpy is doing that as well: `np.array([100, 50], dtype=np.int8).sum()` -> `150`

Comment: @mozway That's correct. The `sum` functions of both pandas and numpy are routines with default behaviors. They are not simply `+` operations.

Comment: @MYousefi Agree to the fact that `+` operation, shown here, does not rely on `pandas`. What about `df['a'] * 4`? Does it also not rely on `pandas` or `numpy` level function?

Comment: Correct. For details on this look for `__add__`, `__radd__` for `+` and , `__mul__`, `__rmul__` for '*' .

Comment: @MYousefi Say someone has down-casted the `int` columns in a dataframe for memory saving. But sometimes arithmetic operations like `df['a'] * 4` might be required on a column whose output can be some up-casted version like `int64`. In that case what is the `pandas` style standard practice, given the problem mentioned with `*`?

Comment: As far as I know pandas/numpy doesn't automatically detect/warn you on such an overflow. However, you can always cast your data before performing the operation. Subsequently you can check the max value of the result against dtype limits, e.g., max of `numpy.iinfo`, to manually detect the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

numpy is doing that as well:

```
np.array([100, 50], dtype=np.int8).sum()
```

Output: `150`

If you must have an int8, perform an explicit conversion:

```
df.sum().astype(np.int8)
```

output:

```
a   -106
dtype: int8
```

Comment: What about  `df['a] * 4`? Please check my comment in the comment-thread against original question. Does it not point towards an inconsistency in the `pandas` and `numpy` framework regarding auto-upcasting policy of `int dtype` in arithmetic operations?